# What is the behavior of 'this.synchronized' in a method in Scala?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency

Suppose I have a class and each method is synchronized with 'this.synchronized'. Does this guarantees that , at certain point in time, only one thread is accessing the class ?

```
class MyClass {

  def x() = this.synchronized {

  }

  def y() = this.synchronized {

  }

}
```

This could seem like a stupid question, but I want to know whether is a difference between 'this.synchronized' and just 'synchronized'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.synchronized` and `synchronized` are the same thing, precisely because for any other method `this.method` is the same as `method` (unless there is another `method` in scope, which is unlikely for `synchronized`).

The `synchronized` method in Scala is equivalent to the `synchronized` block in Java, that is, `obj.synchronized { ... }` is the same as `synchronized(obj) { ... }` in Java (and therefore `this.synchronized` is equivalent to `synchronized(this)`).

For your specific example, it is guaranteed that no two threads can call `x()` and `y()` (or just `x()`, or just `y()`) simultaneously. But this does not hold for other methods inherited from the `Object` class which are not synchronized, for example, `hashCode()` or `equals()`. They can be called in parallel with `x()` and `y()` just fine (not that it is unsafe or something - I don't think that default implementations of these methods can cause races).